# Ruby on Rails, two models in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two very similar models Pretreatment and Diagnosis, that belong to the model Patient:

```
class Pretreatment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  attr_accessible :content
end

class Diagnosis < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  attr_accessible :content
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :age, :name, :city, :street, :number
  has_many :anamneses
  has_many :befunds
end
```

On the `Patient` show page I'm displaying two forms, one for the `Preatreatment` and another for the `Diagnosis`:

```
<%= form_for([@patient, @patient.preatreatments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :conten %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= form_for([@patient, @patient.diagnosiss.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My question is how can I bring the two forms together, so that the user only has to press once the submit button? I`m not sure but I think nested attributes is not the right thing to handle it, maybe the`fields_for` tag?

**Update** I tried to use `fields_for` tag:

```
   <%= form_for([@patient, @patient.pretreatment.build]) do |f| %>
     <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :content %><br />
       <%= f.text_field :content %>
     </div>
     <%= fields_for([@patient, @patient.diagnosiss.build]) do |u| %>
     <div class="field">
       <%= u.label :content %><br />
       <%= u.text_field :content %>
     </div>
     <% end %>
     <div class="actions">
       <%= f.submit %>
     </div>
   <% end %>
```

But I get the error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class in <%= fields_for([@patient,@patient.befunds.build]) do |u| %>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `fields_for` for the associated models.
**There should be no square brackets arround the parameters of `fields_for`**

In your code example, I cannot find the relation between `Patient` and `Diagnosis`, and the plural of diagnosis is **diagnoses**, you can specify this in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'diagnosis','diagnoses'
end
```

So your `Patient` model should contain

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :age, :name, :city, :street, :number
  has_many :diagnoses
end
```

And you can write in your form:

```
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :content %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :content %>
 </div>
 <%= fields_for(@patient, @patient.diagnoses.build) do |u| %>
 <div class="field">
   <%= u.label :content %><br />
   <%= u.text_field :content %>
 </div>
 <% end %>
 <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you - worked great for me. I have a model Option besides my main model for the form, and i was able to add:   <%= fields_for(@option) do |o| %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= o.label :description %><br />
    <%= o.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <% end %> As long as I created an @Option object in the controller.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve that using nested attributes :

patient.rb

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :age, :name,  :pretreatments_attributes, :diagnosiss_attributes
  has_many :pretreatments
  has_many :diagnosiss

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pretreatments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :diagnosiss
end
```

patients_controller.rb

```
def show
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    @patient.pretreatments.build
    @patient.diagnosiss.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @patient }
    end
  end
```

patients/show.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @patient do  |f|%>
    <h3>Pretreatments:</h3>

    <%= f.fields_for :pretreatments do |field| %>
        <%= field.label "Content" %></div>
        <%= field.text_field :content %>
    <% end %>

    <h3>Diagnosis:</h3>

    <%= f.fields_for :diagnosiss do |field| %>
        <%= field.label "Content" %></div>
        <%= field.text_field :content %>
    <% end %>

    <%=f.submit  %>
<% end %>
```

And that all

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways of doing this:

1. The way the `fields_for` works is you have a `form_for` for the parent model and within it you can place `fields_for` the models which belong to the parent. A good example is given in the [Rails Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)
2. A simple and more extensible option over time but not very "semantic" one would be to use JavaScript/JQuery. You could trigger `$("form #new_pretreatments").submit();` and the same for the Diagnosis once a button is clicked.
3. Maybe instead you could have just one model to store them both. For example a model called Disease. Each time a patient gets a disease a new one is created and it has columns for each the Diagnosis and Pretreatment. It's probably the best option instead of adding another model for each bit of info a patient can have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fields_for` for the second model, which works like `form_for` but doesn't generate the form tags. See the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for).

Comment: I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/NDJkC/1/  but i become the error undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class in  <%= fields_for([@patient, @patient.befunds.build]) do |u| %>

Answer (score 1):

There are some gems available for nested forms. one of them is [awesome_nested_fields](https://github.com/lailsonbm/awesome_nested_fields). I haven't used this earlier but that shows good code in documentation. Another one is [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: I dont think nested forms are the right thing to handle it because i dont want to edit the patient and the diagnosis,preatreatment at the same time! I only want that the two models are displayd with only one submit button