# Get first_name (and other info) from Paypal and create Rails Devise account using paypal-recurring gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal

I have create the basics of subscription Paypal using [the RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/289-paypal-recurring-billing) and now I'm doing what is missing there.

Now I'm developing the process to do the Devise user registration together/just after the payment is done. For now, I'm trying something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131395/ruby-on-rails-two-models-in-one-form) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564224/how-to-use-rails-build-to-create-a-user-with-a-stripe-subscription).

As [the RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/289-paypal-recurring-billing) got the e-mail from PayPal using this line:

```
@subscription.email = PayPal::Recurring.new(token: params[:token]).checkout_details.email
```

So, I thought that I could get first name, middle name and last name from PayPal as well. From [PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) it seems that it is possible but I couldn't get it through paypal-recurring gem.
I have tried to see if I can learn what I have to do from [paypal-recurring GitHub](https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring) docs and code but I couln't find and tried some possibilities without success.

Is it possible? Maybe in another way not using paypal-recurring gem?

If you have another recomendation/reference to do this registration process, please, let me know.

**Update**

As @Andrew suggested PayPal IPN, I thought it would be better update my question as I want to have the first_name from PayPal as a default value to ease the process to the user register in my database but he or she may want to change to another name.

The process that I want is something like:

1. The user chooses his plan and to pay with PayPal
2. User is sent to PayPal
3. User fills payment info on PayPal site
4. User is sent again to my site
5. My site gets e-mail and name of the user from PayPal and asks the user to confirm or change the data, and provide his password to create the login to my site
6. My site uses the user data provided to register the user and sends the request to PayPal to request the payment and create the recurring profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on your current outline of steps you can handle that exact flow using [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/#ec).

[SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) will generate a token for you, and you then redirect the user to PayPal.  They review and approve the payment and are then redirected back to your site.  There you can call [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) to obtain the email, name, address, etc. and display a final review page for the customer to confirm everything or make changes if necessary.  Finally, you'd call [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) to finalize the payment using the customers confirmed details.

Comment: Well... It seem that you understand a lot of PayPal, and it seems to work. So, I accepted the answer. However, I won't implement this right now as I implemented using the paypal-recurring gem. In the other hand, I hope I can change the gem in the near future with the help of your answer. So, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would look at [PayPal IPN (Instant Payment Notification)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).  It'll POST transaction details to a listener script you have sitting on your server so you can process the data accordingly in real-time.

Comment: Initially, I thought that this could work but I realized it won't in my case as what I want is to facilitate the registration but the user could want to use another name (maybe as a gift to someone). I will update my question and as you took the time to answer and it can help someone, I will upvote

Comment: If I understand you correctly you can still use IPN to make this happen.  You'd have a couple of options.  First, you could send the name the user wants to use in the CUSTOM parameter of the payment request.  This would come back in IPN so you could pull that value and use it accordingly.  Alternatively, you could save details about the order to your database prior to sending the user over to PayPal.  The order could be saved with a pending status and could include any names necessary, and then you can pass that record ID in the PayPal payment using the INVOICE parameter.

Comment: Again, the INVOICE parameter would come back in the IPN so you could update that record with the payment details accordingly.

Comment: It seems that I couldn't communicate well. So I updated my question again. Either way I will have to study IPN in the next week or so, and I may understand it better.